# Why does the while loop not stop when a variable becomes 0? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a variable called lives in a while loop. I want it to stop the function when it becomes 0. This doesn't happen and when I print the variable it says the value is in the negatives and it doesn't stop the loop. It also has another condition which is players. When I remove that condition, it works. This is really confusing. Can someone explain it to me? (Keep in mind I am not very experienced and I just started learning python)

```
import random
global players
global lives
players = 10
lives = 5
def getRandom():
    players = 10
    lives = 5
    print("There are 9 people around you. You and the computer will both guess a number from 1 to 5. If your numbers are the same, that amount of players will be out, but if your answers are different, you lose a life. You have 5 lives and you get an extra one if you both guess the same number. Good Luck!")
    while(lives > 0 or players > 0):
          myGuess = input("What number do you choose")
          compGuess = random.randint(1,5)
          myGuess = int(myGuess)
          print(f"Computer chose {compGuess}")
          if compGuess == myGuess:
              players = players - compGuess
              if myGuess == 1:
                  print(f"You took out {compGuess} player")
              else:
                print(f"You took out {compGuess} players")
          else:
              lives -= 1
              print(f"You lost a life! You now have {lives} lives remaining")
              print(f"There are {players} players left")
getRandom()
```

Comment: With `or` the whole condition is true, as long as at least one of the conditions is true. With `and` both conditions must be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove those global variables and use arguments in your function. Second, you need to use `and` instead of `or` in your while loop.

```
import random
number_of_players = 10
number_of_lives = 5

def getRandom(lives, players):
    print("There are 9 people around you. You and the computer will both guess a number from 1 to 5. If your numbers are the same, that amount of players will be out, but if your answers are different, you lose a life. You have 5 lives and you get an extra one if you both guess the same number. Good Luck!")
    while(lives > 0 and players > 0):
          myGuess = input("What number do you choose")
          compGuess = random.randint(1,5)
          myGuess = int(myGuess)
          print(f"Computer chose {compGuess}")
          if compGuess == myGuess:
              players = players - compGuess
              if myGuess == 1:
                  print(f"You took out {compGuess} player")
              else:
                print(f"You took out {compGuess} players")
          else:
              lives -= 1
              print(f"You lost a life! You now have {lives} lives remaining")
              print(f"There are {players} players left")
              
getRandom(number_of_lives, number_of_players)
```